# How to resolve the "bad marshal data" error in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kivy, pyinstaller

I have developed a deep learning model with the Keras, a while ago and do not remember the version of Keras and Tensorflow which I used. Now, I have created a Kivy app that uses that model. The problem is that when I try to use the app on my ubuntu device, which has python 3.8, Keras 2.5.0, and Tensorflow 2.5.0, the app works perfectly. But, when I try to use the app on my device which exploits Windows 10, using python 3.8, Keras 2.5.0, and Tensorflow 2.5.0, It fails and raises the error: "bad marshal data(unknown code type)". The reason that I use python 3.7 on windows 10 is that I want to create a .exe file out of my project and pyinstaller does not work properly with python 3.8.
How can I fix the problem? I will appreciate your kind answers since I'm struggling with this issue for about a month.

Comment: You need to include actual details of your model, for example, does your model contain Lambda layers?

Comment: This error generally appears, if model was trained on an older version of python and libraries. If you know what you're doing, you can try to recreate the model's architecture and use its pre-trained weights only.Thanks!